# How to define a Comparator in Java that compares based on two variables

Tags: java, collections

I want to create a comparator to operate such that a process with a lower arrival time will appear first in a sorting, and if two processes have the same arrival time, the one with the lower process id comes first in the sorting. I tried the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone see a flaw in it?

```
public class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process>
{
    public int compare(Process o1, Process o2)
    {
        int result = o1.getArrivalTime() - o2.getArrivalTime();

        if(result == 0)
        {
            return (o1.getPid() < o2.getPid()) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
//        return (result != 0 ? result : o1.getPid() - o2.getPid());
    }
}
```

To be specific, given the processes as follows

```
pid = 0 arrival time = 10
pid = 1 arrival time = 30
pid = 2 arrival time = 15
pid = 3 arrival time = 15
pid = 4 arrival time = 66
```

I get the following ordering at the end

```
Pid = 0 arrival time = 10
Pid = 2 arrival time = 15
Pid = 1 arrival time = 30
Pid = 4 arrival time = 66
Pid = 3 arrival time = 15
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't seem to be working". What are you doing with this? What did you hope would happen? What, exactly, happens instead?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Sorts the wrong way?

Comment: Can you given an example where it does not work and what you expected to happen?

Comment: Bruno Conde helped me figure it out. The comparator it turns out wasn't the problem, it was the function that was displaying the values. Lesson learnt is to not use a foreach loop to show the values of a priority list.

Comment: @Varun Madiath I'd say that lessons is to not sort priority lists

Comment: I'm not sorting a priority list. I constructed a priority list using this comparator.

Comment: but doesn't a priority list have to be sorted by `Pid`? I mean... foreach isn;t the problem, problem is in order inside of a priority list. Btw if you are ansering me, not under my post, i don't get info about it, so plz use @nick next time :)

Comment: @dantuch - I didn't know that the @nick had any real significance on this site. Sorry about that. The thing with a priority list is that it doesn't guarantee that elements in the list are sorted, it only guarantees that the first element in the list is the one with the highest priority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find anything wrong with your comparator. Here is my test case:

```
public class TestComparator {

    static class Process {
        int pid;
        int arrivalTime;

        Process(int pid, int arrivalTime) {
            this.pid = pid;
            this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Process [pid=" + pid + ", arrivalTime=" + arrivalTime + "]";
        }
    }

    static class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process> {
        public int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
            int result = o1.arrivalTime - o2.arrivalTime;

            if (result == 0) {
                return (o1.pid < o2.pid) ? -1 : 1;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Process> processes = Arrays.asList(
                new Process(0, 10),
                new Process(1, 30),
                new Process(2, 15),
                new Process(3, 15),
                new Process(4, 66));

        Collections.sort(processes, new FCFSComparator());

        for (Process process : processes) {
            System.out.println(process);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Process [pid=0, arrivalTime=10]
Process [pid=2, arrivalTime=15]
Process [pid=3, arrivalTime=15]
Process [pid=1, arrivalTime=30]
Process [pid=4, arrivalTime=66]
```

Comment: You're right. I was using a PriorityList to test my code out, and was using a generic foreach loop to test the output of the values instead of the poll function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm making that assumption that the things you are comparing are `int`. In the case of both variables being equal, you are still returning 1 from the inner comparison. Something like this should help:

```
public class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process>
{
    public int compare(Process o1, Process o2)
    {
        int result = o1.getArrivalTime() - o2.getArrivalTime();
        if (result == 0)
        {
            return o1.getPid() - o2.getPid();
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I checked the above code and it does output the correct order. I can only assume you have a bug somewhere else in your code.

```
Pid = 0 arrival time = 10
Pid = 2 arrival time = 15
Pid = 3 arrival time = 15
Pid = 1 arrival time = 30
Pid = 4 arrival time = 66
```

The full test code is:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();
        processes.add(new Process(10, 0));
        processes.add(new Process(30, 1));
        processes.add(new Process(15, 2));
        processes.add(new Process(15, 3));
        processes.add(new Process(66, 4));

        Collections.sort(processes, new FCFSComparator());

        for (Process process : processes)
            System.out.println("Pid = " + process.getPid() + " arrival time = " + process.getArrivalTime());
    }

    static class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process>
    {
        public int compare(Process o1, Process o2)
        {
            int result = o1.getArrivalTime() - o2.getArrivalTime();
            if (result == 0)
            {
                return o1.getPid() - o2.getPid();
            }
            else
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    static class Process
    {
        private int arrivalTime;
        private int pid;

        Process(int arrivalTime, int pid)
        {
            this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
            this.pid = pid;
        }

        public int getArrivalTime()
        {
            return arrivalTime;
        }

        public int getPid()
        {
            return pid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have the same issue as with my code.

Comment: What is the datatype of pid and arrival time?

Comment: @Varun Madiath you tried debuging or printing values of getArrivalTime()? Implementation seems good to me, but it looks like result is always 0

Comment: I've been debugging it for a while now. All the values seem consistent with what I declared them to be.

Comment: One other point is that generating the compare result with subtraction will fail badly if the numbers are very large negative, very large positive as it will silently overflow an int.

Comment: @Jon - pid and arrival time are both integers. And I know of the overflow issues, but in my particular use case, they're never going to occur, so I find it safe to use subtraction. But thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want this:

```
public class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process> {
    public int compare(Process o1, Process o2) {
        if (o1.getArrivalTime() == o2.getArrivalTime()) {
            return (o1.getPid() < o2.getPid()) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return (o1.getArrivalTime() < o2.getArrivalTime()) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried dropping this in as a replacement, and I got the same output as what my code above gives me.

Comment: Oops, yeah I notice now this is effectively the same thing. I tried your data set and it works for me with either implementation. You might want to try including your `Process` class, at least the `getPid()` and `getArrivalTime()` methods.

Comment: Those are simple accessor methods. The issue was solved, and right now I'm trying to prevent myself banging my head against the table for being so utterly foolish.

Comment: Hehe, no worries :) At least SO helped you realize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is:

```
public class FCFSComparator implements Comparator<Process>
{
    public int compare(Process o1, Process o2)
    {
        int timeCmp = Integer.valueOf(o1.getArrivalTime()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getArrivalTime()));
        return (timeCmp != 0 ? timeCmp : Integer.valueOf(o1.getPid()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getPid())));
    }
}
```